# Module and Modules needs to be merged/linked

Tags: discussion, tags

[module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/module) and [modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/modules) needs to be symlinked/merged

Comment: This has been taken care of as part of [this meta thread](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3924/synonimization-of-singular-plural-tag-pairs). You can either delete it, close it or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

Both tag contains similar questions, so symlinked or merging is necessary. My suggestion for the master tag is [modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/modules)